# Style UIlabel text like the font in the Settings panel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

How do you style a UILabel text like the text below (created using `titleForFooterInSection`)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below , you might need to alter the values of color and Size, Try with different-2 combination  of both..

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
```

See the UILabel Documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html

Comment: I've sort of matched the shadow using headerText.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        headerText.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1); but what is the font color?

Comment: @daidai: could be "grayColor" :)

Comment: no, this is the point - the image above is blue-ish, grayColor doesnt match the color above.

Comment: @daidai: you could find the color with some others external tools like PhotoShop .. ColorUtility in Mac ..

Comment: I know but I'm not getting it right, this was the point of my question, does anyone know the UIColor of it?

Comment: @daidai:  you could get the RGB value using "ColorSync" in Mac.  then construct a UIColor object using "initWithRed" method of "UIColor" class .. This could be the easy solution of your problem..

Comment: Ta for your help got it...see answer below

Comment: it did, its not the right answer, so for anyone else wanting to copy the style above, use the code below.

Answer (score 1):

```
 label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
 label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.5];
 label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
 label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(76.0f/255.0f) green:(86.0f/255.0f) blue:(108.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
```